# Apollo- React - Do not get data when requesting missing/optional fields

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo, react-apollo, apollo-client

I want to get the data referring to a dog from a GraphQL API. Some of the fields returned should not be nullable while others can be. In the below request, the `name` and the `surname` of the owner are always present, while the address is a string and is optional.

```
const GET_DOG = gql`
 query GetDog($dogId: String!) {
  getDog(dogId: $dogId) {
    owner {
     name
     surname
     address
    }
  }
}
```

As I want to load my data after clicking a button I use useLazyQuery to get them:

```
const [getDog, {data}] = useLazyQuery(GET_DOG, {
  variables: {
    dogId
  }
},
onCompleted(data) {
  console.log('data retrieved', data)
 }
)
```

The GraphQL API for some dogs doesn't have the address at all, the field `address` is not returned back in the response. In the network tab, the response is 200 OK and I can see the rest data returned as expected.

On the other side though, as the field `address` is missing, Apollo throws a warning in the console that `address` is missing and the `data` after the request completion are `undefined`. If I dont request for the address field, then the data are retrieved as expected.

So, the question is how we can query optional fields with Apollo Graphql?

Comment: with this query `address` is requested then required in response, if missing - bad API behaviour, not graphql compliant

Comment: Isn't there a way that I can request any optional field ? If not this means that the API must return all optional fields with null values?.. Also in the network tab the response is 200 OK and I can see the data ..

Comment: should return nulls for all not resolved [and not nullable] fields

Comment: But this doesn't make sense! In the network the response is returned back correctly... The schemas defined imply that for the response of this API, this field can be optional... So, why the API has to return back this field? Is there possibly an official specs either in Apollo docs or GraphQL that in the above cases of the API should return nl for all not resolved fields?

Comment: google for general graphql specs? ... response should contain all requested fields (for query with `owner { name surname address }` it must return value for all 3 fields, `address` can be `null`, if you don't need `address` then remove it from query), optional field means it can have null value and type is still valid

Comment: You know what surprises me that if you add in the useLazyQuery the parameter => fetch-policy:'no-cache' the data are retrieved as expected ... Why Apollo doesn't complain it this case?

Comment: what if query contains ids `getDog(dogId: $dogId) { id owner { id name ...` ? normalizing cache needs ids

Comment: I'm getting similar behavior.  I see the data I'm requesting in the network tab, but it's not present in the result.  Feels like a bug in apollo client.  What apolloClient version are you using?

Comment: not bug, cache needs unique, recognizable entries, by default using id/_id property - if missing entries can be overwritten, duplicated, missing etc.